# ngrx action: how to test that action is dispatched

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

How to unit test whether an action was dispatched?

for example I have this simple method

```
 public openInfo()
  {
    this.store.dispatch(InfoActions.openInfo({
      Configuration: {
        message: 'This is an info message!'
      }
    }));
  }
```

I need to write a unit test that verifies that the action is dispatched:

```
   it('should dispatch openInfo action', function () {

    // how to check the dispactched actions and their parameters?
    // expect(...)
  });
```

How can I check the dispatched actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to. You need to use spies on the store.

Create a spy on store.dispatch and use

```
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)
```

And you are done. The actual testing of the dispatching falls into the store unit test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all spy on the store before the dispatch happens:

```
const spyDispatch = spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
```

Afterwards, you can expect for a complex action (where is hard to recreate):

```
const myActionType = InfoActions.openInfo.type;
expect(spyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({ type: myActionType  }));
```

You can find more about `jasmine.objectContaining` here:

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.objectContaining%3C/code%3E